# Cannot Set Height in Pixels via CSS on Block-Level DIV

Tags: html, css, chromium

I have an application with a block-level `<div>` that does not seem to obey a `height` CSS property. In most browsers, it does, but in Chromium, it does not. Here are some relevant snapshots:

### The Trouble Maker

... highlighted in gray.

[image: Trouble]

### Chromium

As you can see, the height of the element is about 3(ish)px with a 20px margin.

[image: Chromium]
[image: Chromium]

### Google Chrome, Firefox, and others

However, in all other browsers, the height renders as 20px with a 20px margin, just fine.

[image: Google Chrome]
[image: Google Chrome]

### What I've tried

- Manually specifying the height. I have to set the height to `250px` before the actual, rendered height will reach `20px`

[image: Chromium]

- Vertically align the text to the top
- Various `display` types

Any ideas on why the height isn't set properly, only in Chromium?

Comment: Any floated children?

Comment: @PaulRedmond Good check. No, it only contains some text. I've updated my answer to show some of the DOM.

Comment: @OliverSpryn, please add the CSS code used (not the inherited stuff, the default browser styling gets mixed in) or better, create a fiddle. ;)

Comment: have you tried just using !important at the end of your height statement? seems like user agent sheet is over riding is all. maybe i'm wrong but worth a shot, without your actual CSS, hard to say, but give it a try.

Comment: @SkullDev I had forgotten to mention that. I know that it is !important to add the !important to the end of the statement. So, yes, I tried adding !important to height. :)

Comment: Have you got a codepen or fiddle at all where you could paste everything in for us to view then? Thanks for getting back to me either way, just wondered.

Comment: Have you included `<!doctype html>`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was able to fix this issue by constraining the height of the `<div>` above the troublesome `<div>`:

```
div.place-to-put-evidence {
   ...

   height: calc(100% - 20px) !important;
}
```

All fixed now. Thanks for the pointers!